# Where can I find documentation that state sales tax was paid in the 1980s when an aircraft was purchased?

Tags: general-aviation

I am going from a sole owner to a partnership with two others in a Cherokee 140.  The state wants proof that state sales tax was paid in the 1980s when a family member originally purchased the airplane.

I have informally been a partner in the airplane since that time and have been paying half the bills. My partner recently passed away. I'm sure the state sales tax was paid but cannot find any documentation. They won't process the new registration until I can provide documentation that the state sales tax was paid, or I have to pay the fee again.

Where can I find a record that the state sales tax was paid when the aircraft was originally purchased by my family member?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I assume you're in the USA? It might be helpful to mention which state you're in. You can request all the documentation that the FAA has for an aircraft, but the FAA has nothing to do with state sales tax. It's not really an aviation question as such, it's more about how to find old tax records in your state. If you don't get a good answer here, you might try [money.SE](http://money.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: This is really not an aviation-related question - it's a tax and recordkeeping question. It  *might* be more topical over on [money.SE], but really the answer is probably going to be "You need to find records demonstrating the tax was paid, like a cancelled check or a receipt for payment." (Alternatively consult a local CPA to see about telling the tax authority in your state "You're talking about a 30-year-old sale, you're clearly out of your minds - get stuffed." - I believe the IRS is limited to 10 years, but your state's law may say otherwise…)

Comment: You may have already done this, but the [Wisconsin Department of Transportation's website](http://wisconsindot.gov/Pages/doing-bus/aeronautics/ac-rgstrtn/default.aspx) says, "If you have questions regarding sales or use tax contact the Department of Revenue at (608) 261-7694."

Answer (score 2):

This is a state level issue (here in the US) and you will have to contact the state in question. While aircraft are registered federally the sales tax is state imposed (and collected). If the family does not have the documentation you may have to go through some hoops to get it. Its also important to add what state you are in as that may change the answer to the question.

Furthermore depending on how you are setting up the new partnership there are tax implications to that as well. You should talk to a lawyer about the various ways this can impact things. Unfortunately in the eyes of the state you had no stake in the plane (despite your informal ownership, the state is only worried about formal ownership).

Comment: The aircraft is in Wisconsin.